# Refresh ui-router view when state parameters change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What's the correct way to update a ui-router view when state parameters change?

For example, if I've got a state like:

```
.state("page.view", {
    url: "/pages/:slug",
    views: {
        "": {
            controller: "PageCtrl",
            templateUrl: "page-view.html",
        },
    },
})
```

And an (incorrect) controller which looks like this:

```
.controller("PageCtrl", function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.page = loadPageFromSlug($state.params.slug);
})
```

How can I correctly load a new `$scope.page` when the `$state.slug` changes?

**Note** that the above does not work when moving from page to another because the controller is only run once, when the first page loads.

Answer (score 10):

I would do something like this:

```
.controller("PageCtrl", function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function updatePage() {
        $scope.page = $state.params.slug;
    });       
});
```

I'd be curious if you find a better way - there may be some way to just watch the value of the state slug, but this is clean and clearly articulates what it is that you're watching for.

Comment: This… would definitely work. But… damn, it feels like a bit of a heavyweight solution for what I would assume — possibly naively? — to be an exceptionally common problem.

Comment: It's not at all heavyweight, though - you're listening to a simple event, that's already being fired. It's about the lightest weight solution to this problem I can think of. $scope.$watch with a function is adding a lot more overhead, I would think.

Comment: Err, sorry, I mean heavyweight in terms of "it feels like a weird solution to what should be a common problem"?

Answer (score 2):

I am really not fully sure, if I do not miss something here - but, based on the snippets shown in your question:

- `PageCtrl` is related to state "page.view" and will be run **as many times as** "page.view" state is triggered
- `"page.view"` state has declared param **slug** - `url: "/pages/:slug",`, which will trigger state change - whenever it is changed
- If the above is true (if I do not oversee something) we can use [stateConfig](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateprovider-1)  setting - [**resolve**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#resolve)
- there is no need to use `$state.params`. We can use `$stateParams` (more UI-Router way I'd personally say)

Well if all that is correct, as shown in [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3F4ybfQZ7Tj5YNvMSPgy?p=preview), we can do it like this

resolver:

```
var slugResolver = ['$stateParams', '$http'
                   , function resolveSlug($stateParams, $http){

  return $http
    .get("slugs.json")
    .then(function(response){
      var index = $stateParams.slug;
      return response.data[index];
    });

}];
```

Adjusted state def:

```
.state("page.view", {
    url: "/pages/:slug",
    views: {
      "": {
        controller: "PageCtrl",
        templateUrl: "page-view.html",
        resolve: { slug :  slugResolver },
      },
    },
})
```

And the PageCtrl:

```
.controller('PageCtrl', function($scope,slug) {
  $scope.slug = slug;
})
```

Check it all in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3F4ybfQZ7Tj5YNvMSPgy?p=preview)

Comment: While this seems the correct way to do it, it does not work when you use the same controller in some directive. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in ui-router 0.2.14. After upgrading to 0.2.18 a parameter change does fire the expected `$stateChange*` events.